# Modal only showing the first label, but then the rest of the HTML is cut off

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, bootstrap-modal

**EDIT 2:** I found a way to make it work, but it doesn't seem like this is how it should work. Maybe I am used to C# which just makes sense to me and this doesn't haha. Anyways, I changed my javascript. If this is completely dumb it would be nice to know. Thanks SO for being my sounding board as always. =)

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".btnModal").click(function () {
        var paymentId = $(this).data('id');//get the id of the selected item
        var phoneNumber = $(this).data('phone');//get the phone number of the selected item
        var locationNumber = $(this).data('locationNumber');//get the locationNumber of the selected item

        var modalDisplay = document.getElementById("modalPaymentId");
        
        modalDisplay.innerHTML += "Id: <label>" + paymentId + "</label><br />";
        modalDisplay.innerHTML += "Phone: <label>" + phoneNumber + "</label><br />";
        modalDisplay.innerHTML += "Number: <label>" + locationNumber + "</label><br />";
        modalDisplay.innerHTML += "Num2: <label>" + locationNumber + "</label>";
    });
</script>
```

**EDIT:** I am onto something here, but haven't found the fix yet. It seems that when I set the text in the javascript, it really does cut off everything. I am trying to come up with how to format this javascript. Any help is appreciated.

---

The only thing that displays is the Id: [myIdNumber] and nothing at all after that. All the fields have values which are being passed into them. Not even the label for location number and phone are displaying. It is like the rest of the modal is just cut off after it displays some data (which it is being cut off since nothing after displays in the developer tools when debugging). You can see I have changed how I am populating the modal data and no matter what it cuts off after displaying the first value. **IMPORTANT is if I comment out the first value it will display Id: Phone: [myPhoneNumber]. So something is killing the rest of the modal div after it starts displaying my value.** Any ideas what is doing that?

HTML for modal

```
@* Modal popup of product summary *@
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Payment Summary</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    Id:
                    <label class="modalPaymentId" type="text" name="paymentId" id="modalPaymentId" />
                    <br />
                    Phone:
                    <label class="modalPhone" type="text" name="phoneNumber" id="modalPhoneNumber" />
                    <br />
                    Location Number:
                    <label class="modalLocationNumber" type="text" name="locationNumber" id="modalLocationNumber" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
```

JavaScript for modal

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".btnModal").click(function () {
            var paymentId = $(this).data('id');//get the id of the selected item
            var phoneNumber = $(this).data('phone');//get the phone number of the selected item
            var locationNumber = $(this).data('locationNumber');//get the locationNumber of the selected item
            //document.getElementById("modalPaymentId").innerHTML = paymentId;
            //document.getElementById("modalPhoneNumber").innerHTML = phoneNumber;
            $('.modalPaymentId').text(paymentId);//set the id to the input on the modal
            $('.modalPhone').text(phoneNumber);//set the phone number to the input on the modal
            $('.modalLocationNumber').text(locationNumber);//set the modalLocationNumber to the input on the modal
        });
    </script>
```

This is the button that calls the modal

```
     <button data-id="@item.PaymentId" data-phone="@item.Phone" data-locationNumber="@item.LocationNum" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" class="btnModal"> Summary </button>
```

Comment: [`<label>` element](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-label-element)'s end tag cannot be omitted. Unless you have a template parser which adds the ending `</label>` for you, you have to write them as `<label>Some label</label>`.

Comment: Ah! That makes so much sense! Thank you! Now I know for next time.